# I keep getting Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object posting with sqli query

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, slim

I am grabbing data from a MySQL database in phpMyAdmin. I then load that data into multiple text boxes on a form. The user can edit this data then press the `Save Changes` button which is the `submit` button on my form. When the submit button is run it should run the function below `$app->post('/admin-edit-stack'` and update the data in the database, but instead I get the error message.

I have looked over documentation and other examples, but I cant see what I am doing wrong to output this error!

The full error message is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in index.php on line 117
```

This is the full update function:

```
$app->post('/admin-edit-stack', isAuthenticated($app),function () use($app,$data, $stacks, $link){
    $id = $_POST['stack-id'];
    $name = $_POST['stack-name'];
    $slug = $_POST['stack-slug'];
    $icon = $_POST['stack-icon'];
    $sql = $link->prepare("UPDATE stacks WHERE ID=? SET Name=?, Slug=?, Icon = ?");
>>> $sql->bind_param("isss", $id, $name, $slug, $icon);  <<<ERROR HERE
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->close();
    $app->view()->appendData(array("username" => getUsername($app)));
    $app->redirect($app->urlFor('admin'));
})->name('admin-edit-stack');
```

This is the html form code which runs the function on submit:

```
<form class="forms" method="POST" action="/admin-edit-stack">
    <input type="hidden" name="stack-id" value="{{data.ID}}">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Name" name="stack-name" value="{{data.Name}}"></br>
    <label>Slug: </label>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Slug" name="stack-slug" value="{{data.Slug}}"></br>
    <label>Icon: </label>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Icon" name="stack-icon" value="{{data.Icon}}"></br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="icon-check"></i> Save Changes</button>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/admin"><i class="icon-remove-circle"></i> Cancel</a>
</form>
```

Here is an image of the form:

[image]

I just realized the SET and WHERE sections were the wrong way round. Here is the new function:

```
$app->post('/admin-edit-stack', isAuthenticated($app),function () use($app,$data, $stacks, $link){
$id = $_POST['stack-id'];
$name = $_POST['stack-name'];
$slug = $_POST['stack-slug'];
$icon = $_POST['stack-icon'];
if ($sql = $link->prepare("UPDATE stacks SET Name=?, Slug=?, Icon = ? WHERE ID=?")){
$sql->bind_param("isss", $id, $name, $slug, $icon);
$sql->execute();
        $sql->close();
}
else {
    //Error
    printf("Prep statment failed: %s\n", $link->error);
}
$app->view()->appendData(array("username" => getUsername($app)));
$app->redirect($app->urlFor('admin'));
})->name('admin-edit-stack');
```

This now outputs no error message, but still doesn't update the database.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing any error checking on the `$sql = $link->prepare()` call. You'll get this error on the `bind_params` line if the previous line fails and thus `$sql` is not set correctly.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

You can do your error handling in two ways:

1. Switch on PDO exceptions, and use `try ... catch` error handling.
2. check for `$sql` not being set, which will tell you that an error has occurred, and then use `$link->errorCode()` to find out more about the error if you need to.

Comment: Cheers @Spudley, that helped me find the problem.. but it still doesn't seem to update the database. I have put the edited code above, any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I just spotted that you're using mysqli... I was thinking PDO, as that's what I'm used to. Same basic things apply, but I'm a bit rusty with mysqli.

Comment: Suggestion: Try wrapping all your table and field names in back-ticks. -- ``UPDATE `stacks` SET `Name`=?, `Slug`=?, `Icon` = ? WHERE `ID`=?``. This will avoid issues if you're using fieldnames that are mySQL reserved words (I don't think you are, but it's good practice anyway). Also check your capitalisation; eg do your field names actually have upper case field letter? mySQL is sensitive to these things.

Comment: I got it working now, I the `if ($sql = $link->prepare("UPDATE stacks SET Name=?, Slug=?, Icon = ? WHERE ID=?")){
$sql->bind_param("isss", $id, $name, $slug, $icon);` didn't match. So I was updating the name with the ID etc.

All sorted now, thanks for the help!